# Массив указателей на объекты наследованных классов

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, указатели, объекты

Можно ли сделать один массив указателей  для всех объектов наследованных классов? Подскажите может главу в учебнике хотя бы)

Comment: можно. Заносить в глобальный список ссылку на себя в конструкторе базового класса.

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Если речь идет о полиморфной иерархии классов, то массив указателей на *базовый* класс как раз и будет массивом "универсальных указателей", которые могут указывать на объекты любых производных классов. Для того полиморфизм и предназначен. А если это не то, что вам нужно, то тогда объясняйте более детально, о чем идет речь.

Comment: Да все верно, разобрался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, имеется в виду что-то такое ([ideone](http://ideone.com/mLVF0j)):

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Base {
    // ...
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
    // ...
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
    // ...
};

int main() {
    vector<Base *> vector_of_pointers;
    vector_of_pointers.push_back(new Base());
    vector_of_pointers.push_back(new Derived1());
    vector_of_pointers.push_back(new Derived2());
    return 0;
}
```

Или такое ([ideone](http://ideone.com/BlNVyv))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    static vector<Base *> all_objects_of_this_class_or_subclasses;

    static void print_summary_of_objects(int step) {
        printf("В массиве указателей на шаге %d находится %d указателей\n", step, all_objects_of_this_class_or_subclasses.size());
    }

    Base() {
        all_objects_of_this_class_or_subclasses.push_back(this);
    }

    ~Base() {
        auto it = find(all_objects_of_this_class_or_subclasses.begin(), all_objects_of_this_class_or_subclasses.end(), this);
        all_objects_of_this_class_or_subclasses.erase(it);
    }
};

vector<Base *> Base::all_objects_of_this_class_or_subclasses;

class Derived1 : public Base {
    // ...
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
    // ...
};

int main() {
    Base::print_summary_of_objects(0);

    Base *base = new Base();
    Base::print_summary_of_objects(1);

    Derived1 *derived1 = new Derived1();
    Base::print_summary_of_objects(2);

    delete base;
    Base::print_summary_of_objects(3);

    Derived2 *derived2 = new Derived2();
    Base::print_summary_of_objects(4);

    delete derived2;
    Base::print_summary_of_objects(5);

    delete derived1;
    Base::print_summary_of_objects(6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: первый вариант работает, удивительно как просто.. )) сейчас попробую второй. Спасибо!

Comment: Если что, эти два варианта решают разные задачи)

Comment: мне нужно чтобы указатели автоматически добавлялись в массив при создании объектов с аргументами, координаты x, y к примеру. Для дальнейшего их вызова или пере-инициализации в процессе работы

Comment: Если хотите чтобы автоматически добавлялись, то должен подойти второй вариант

Comment: Закинул 13 объектов разных классов

for (vector<Global*>::iterator it = Global::all_objects_of_this_class_or_subclasses.begin() ; it!=Global::all_objects_of_this_class_or_subclasses.end() ; ++it)
        cout<<*it << "   ";

выводит разные адреса всех 13 объектов, вроде бы работает)

Comment: ерунду я написал))). удалять указатели, занулять указатели, удалять объект вроде научился, удалять нули, а вот общаться к объекту и его переменным невышло

Comment: Что-нибудь вроде `all_objects_of_this_class_or_subclasses[0]->имя_поля` не подойдёт?

Comment: Все, я понял в чем была ошибка, у меня просто нули выводил одни, хотя обьекты в координатах. Я просто при передачи координат в конструктор сразу передавал их в функции а нужно было промежуточные переменные сделать, типа X = x, Y = y. Забыл переделать.

Все работает, спасибо большое!!!))) за терпение

Comment: @Anton, не за что)

Comment: Подскажи а как обращаться к функциям объектов ? у меня он их не видит вообще если функцию писать только в унаследованом классе. А если функцию прописать в глобальном классе там где вектор объетов то пишет  main.cpp|203|undefined reference to `Global::update()'|

Comment: Если не сложно, приведи, пожалуйста, код, который не компилируется (желательно отдельным вопросом).

Comment: похоже без вас не разобраться - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704060/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2/704102#704102

Comment: Посмотрел вопрос, тебе вроде ответ написали, кажется что он тебе подошёл (если нет, то напиши что не так или задай новый вопрос)